# Storing data below the stack pointer?

Tags: x86, stack

Looking at the disassembly (along with an instruction trace) of ld.so installed in Ubuntu 9.04, I swear I'm seeing data being stored below the stack pointer (i.e., beyond the top of the stack) at times. This seems insane to me, but maybe this is more common than I think. Does this happen often?

Here's what I see:

`ebp: 0xBF8269E8, esp: 0xBF8269DC`

```
c98:       8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
c9b:       8d 14 06                lea    (%esi,%eax,1),%edx
c9e:       8b 83 28 03 00 00       mov    0x328(%ebx),%eax
ca4:       3b 50 04                cmp    0x4(%eax),%edx
```

Comment: Can we get a little more context?  Is the value stored at -0x10(%ebp) ever used later in the function?  Could it be a function parameter?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly leads you to believe that stuff is being stored below the *stack* pointer. All I can see is a negative offset from `ebp` which is the *frame* pointer.

This is typically used as a pointer to the next stack frame up from the current for a number of reasons.

- Either side of `ebp` are the parameters passed in to this function (above `ebp`) and locals for this function (below `ebp`). Using `-0x10(%ebp)` just means that you're doing something with a local variable.
- It easy to revert to the previous stack frame just by loading `%esp` with `%ebp` and returning.

Of course, you *may* be hitting something below `%esp` but that would depend on the data being loaded, which isn't actually shown in your sample.

A "diagram" may help:

```
     +------------------------+
     | Parameters passed to x |
     +------------------------+
     | Return address         |
%ebp +------------------------+
     | Locals for x           |
%esp +------------------------+
```

My memory of this is rusty (the specific instruction may not be exact but they should be good enough to indicate the concept behind it), but the typical function calling sequence is:

- caller pushes parameters on the stack (`push`, `push`, ...).
- caller pushes current `%ebp` on to the stack (`push %ebp`).
- caller loads `%ebp` with `%esp%` (`mov %ebp, %esp`).
- caller calls callee (`call XYZ`).
- callee allocates space for locals (`sub %esp,N`).
- callee can then use `(%ebp+N)` for parameters, `(%ebp-N)` for locals.

And, for returning:

- callee loads `%esp` with `%ebp` (`mov %esp, %ebp`).
- callee returns to caller (`ret`).
- caller pops previous `%ebp` off the stack (`pop %ebp`).
- caller cleans up parameter section (`add %esp,N`).

Comment: Thanks. Most of that I think I knew (although that is a great summary). It makes sense that you'd go as low as (%ebp-N) (or maybe N-4 since there's a call in there), which still keeps you within the bounds of the current stack pointer. But in the example I'm citing, -0x10(%ebp) would look into memory 4 bytes below the current stack pointer (0xBF8269D8, whereas esp is 0xBF8269DC). That's something I haven't seen, and I wanted a sanity check to see if this trace represents something reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Signal handlers need to be able to create a stack frame anytime. Therefore you always need to follow your ABI's stack protocol.

On PowerPC, a certain number of bytes (half a kilobyte?) are reserved below the stack pointer. (Of course, this may vary between platforms.) Signal handlers then have to waste that much space to avoid interfering with anything. The advantage being elimination of the store+subtract and add instructions that would create a frame for very small leaf functions.